# macOS - How do I use checkbox in NSTableView?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit

I'm trying to put checkbox to the first column of a view based tableView. I dragged a check box button to the column, then the structure is like

```
Table View
    First Column
        Check
            Check
        Text Cell
```

Then in the `tableView` method of the view controller I'm doing

```
if identifier == "Check" {
    let cell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "Check"), owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
    return cell
}
```

I get a run time error `Could not cast value of type 'NSButton' to 'NSTableCellView'`, what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: You are mixing the cell-based and view-based table view together.

Comment: Have a look at the [Documentation about Cell based tables](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingCellTables/PopulatingCellTables.html). Probably also of interest could be [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/143828/macos-nstableview-tutorial)

Comment: Which view has identifier "Check"?

Comment: I'm not very clear about view-based and cell-based, I checked my table's attributes inspector, it shows it's view based. I just follow the documentation to create the table, it seems I didn't add any NSCell object to it https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/CreatingViewBasedTablesInIB/CreatingViewBasedTablesInIB.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i-CH4-SW1

Comment: @Willeke `First Column` and its child `Check` which is NSButton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty simple.

In a view based `NSTableView` you can use any view which inherits from `NSView` as table cell view. The default is `NSTableCellView` with a text field but it's also possible to use control objects like `NSTextField` or `NSButton` **without** any underlying custom view just by dragging them into the table view canvas.

The error occurs because you have to cast the created view to the proper type. If you are using a checkbox cast the view to `NSButton`.

Don't think in terms of **cell**, think in terms of **view**. I even recommend to name the variable as `view` rather than as `cell`.

The `NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier` extension is the recommended pattern to define constants

```
extension NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier {
    static let check = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "Check")
}
```

---

```
let view = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: .check, owner: self) as! NSButton
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSTableCellView` has a `imageView` and a `textField` outlet. You need a checkbox and you can add one. Subclass `NSTableCellView` and add an outlet 'checkBox'. In IB, change the class of the cell view, replace the textfield by a checkbox (or add a checkbox) and connect the 'checkBox' outlet. In `tableView(_:viewFor:row:)`, use `checkBox` instead of `textField`.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier {
     static let lhsCellImage = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("lhsCellImage")
     static let lhsCellName = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("lhsCellName")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    if tableColumn?.identifier == .lhsCellImage {
        let cellView = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: .lhsCellImage, owner: self) as! IDMainTableImageCellView
        let imageNameStr = tableImageList[row]
        let imageName = NSImage(named:  imageNameStr as NSImage.Name)
        cellView.tableCellImageView.image = imageName
        return cellView
    } else if tableColumn?.identifier == .lhsCellName {
        let cellView = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: .lhsCellName, owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
        cellView.textField?.stringValue = tableDataList[row]
        return cellView
    } else{
        return nil
    }
}
```